# animated transition of UIView, delay between points of path

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I made animation path which consists of 3 curves. When animation is executed it works well, but there is delay of 1 sec (approximately) between each curve motions. 
How can I avoid this delay?

Here is how i added subpaths:

```
path.AddCurveToPoint (
    new PointF (x, y), 
    new PointF (x - xControl, new_y - (new_y - y)/2.0f),
    new PointF (x, new_y));
path.AddCurveToPoint (
    new PointF (x, y), 
    new PointF (x -xControl, new_y + (new_y - y)/2.0f),
    new PointF (x, new_y));
path.AddCurveToPoint (
    new PointF (x, y), 
    new PointF (x + xControl, new_y - (new_y - y)/2.0f),
    new PointF (x, new_y));
```

Comment: Can you post your full animation code?

Comment: The solution is to set key frame animation type:
pathAnimation.CalculationMode = CAKeyFrameAnimation.AnimationPaced;